# MySQL query with regular expression

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a MySQL table with some addresses on it. I would like to find the addresses that contain double letters between the 5th and 11th position. There is a test table with some data for reference.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
address VARCHAR(500));

INSERT INTO test (address)
VALUES ('Western Marrow'),
('Kennffort Plains'),
('Oaksbrook Terrace'),
('Southern Old Saybrook')
```

The last record 'Southern Old Saybrook' should not appear because its double letter is not within the 5th and 11th position.
Now, I have used this query to get the double letters:

```
SELECT address
from test
WHERE address REGEXP 'a{2}|b{2}|c{2}|d{2}|e{2}|f{2}|g{2}|h{2}|i{2}|j{2}|k{2}|l{2}|m{2}|n{2}|o{2}|p{2}|q{2}|r{2}|s{2}|t{2}|u{2}|v{2}|w{2}|x{2}|y{2}|z{2}';
```

But I am failing to conduct the search within the given range. How could I modify the query to apply the regular expression within the range?

Comment: What about the third sentence? 'Oaksbrook Terrace' Should match?

Comment: Yes it should match because the letter contains two o within the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUBSTR()` to get the substring between 5th and 11th position.

```
WHERE SUBSTR(address, 5, 6) REGEXP '...'
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr for reference

Comment: Thank you. it works! I mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Much shorter than the hastily accepted answer:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(address, 5, 6) REGEXP '([a-z])\\1'
```

Caveat:  Only checked on MySQL 8.0.

Caveat:  Case folding or not is determined by collation of the string.

Comment: Much shorter code. Thank you. But I don't know what the \\1 means. I will look into it.

Comment: `\\1` means to use what was found by the first ("1") match (`(...)`).  In your case -- same letter twice.